# Why apache server not working with bettercap?

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04, ettercap

hello i have ubuntu server 14 and I have bettercap and Apache Server  , mysql , php5 when bettercap working apache stop working I need the two to work together

Answer (score 0):

change bettercap http-ui port by copying http-ui.cap caplet file and change the following lines :

```
set api.rest.address 127.0.0.1
set api.rest.port 8081
set http.server.address 127.0.0.1
set http.server.port 8088
```

remember to start bettercap with the changed caplet configuration.
more info at : [api docs](https://www.bettercap.org/modules/core/api.rest/)